# Asp.net MVC prevent automatic conversion of url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a Asp.net MVC 2 project. My start page has following link:

```
http://localhost:2666/Home/Index?SomeID=4f62c452-4513-4dd0-b235-830d721815e4
```

but when I use RedirectToAction method it will be changed to the short version below:

```
http://localhost:2666/?SomeID=4f62c452-4513-4dd0-b235-830d721815e4
```

I want to include a link to a relative URL. (for example "xyz/test" which should be converted to "http://localhost:2666/xyz/test" which does not work if the URL is changed. Can I somehow prevent this - or is there a better another (better) way of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add something like this before your "Default" route in the Global.asax it should work for you.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "xyzRoute",                                        
    "xyz/test",                           
    new { controller = "xyz", action = "test" }
);
```

Comment: You are right! That works - thank you. Although I don't really understand 100% why it works. Any chance you could give me a little hint?

Comment: The "Default" route is sort of a catch all and any time you hit "Index" of a controller it will strip off "Controller/Index". By adding "xyzRoute" before "Default", MVC will use that instead and will not shorten the route.